# How to find document using $eq in MongoDB from Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

This is the next.js code I am using to get a document from MongoDB using unique slug:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  const postSlug = context.params.postPage;

  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
  const posts = await db
    .collection("posts")
    .find({ slug: { $eq: postSlug } })
    .toArray();

  return {
    props: {
      posts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)),
    },
  };
}
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/gssapi.js:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./pages/[videoPage].js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

My MongoDB data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Post": "this is a post",
    "_id": ObjectId("630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"),
    "slug": "this-is-a-title",
    "title": "This is a title"
  },
  {
    "Post": "this is a post",
    "_id": ObjectId("630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a1"),
    "slug": "this-is-a-titleb",
    "title": "This is a titleB"
  }
]
```

It's working if I hardcode my slug like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
  const posts = await db
    .collection("posts")
    .find({ slug: { $eq: "this-is-a-titleb" } })
    .toArray();

  return {
    props: {
      posts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)),
    },
  };
}
```

How can I pass slug dynamically to find the document I need?

Comment: Can you verify that `postSlug` is set to the value you expect?

Comment: @rickhg12hs You are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I just deleted and recreated my database in MongoDB and it's now working with everything (Symbols, Different languages, Special characters) in the slug.